# Group Data and show group as separte column

Tags: sql-server-2014

We have following Data

```
----------------------------
RollNo        |  Seat
----------------------------
A1234         |   GN
A1233         |   GN
A1235         |   GNF
A1238         |   GN
A1233         |   GNF
A1231         |   GN
A1232         |   GNP
```

How can we get data in following format. Using SQL Only

```
----------------------------------------
GN       |     GNF     |  GNP
----------------------------------------
A1234    |  A1235      | A1232         
A1233    |  A1233      | 
A1238    |             | 
A1231    |             |
```

I am using MS SQL SERVER

Comment: What you are looking for is the PIVOT function.  It's typically used to provide aggregation, but you can manipulate it to do what you want.  Your question is basically a version of this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a PIVOT and ROW_NUMBER function in order to accomplish your objective.  See the example below.

**The Setup**

```
DECLARE @Seats AS TABLE
    (
    RollNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Seat CHAR(3) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @Seats
        ( RollNo, Seat )
VALUES  ('A1234','GN')
        ,('A1233','GN')
        ,('A1235','GNF')
        ,('A1238','GN')
        ,('A1233','GNF')
        ,('A1231','GN')
        ,('A1232','GNP');
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT GN, GNF, GNP
FROM (
    SELECT RollNo
        , Seat
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Seat ORDER BY RollNo) AS GroupID
    FROM @Seats) AS T PIVOT (MAX(RollNo) FOR Seat IN (GN, GNF, GNP)
    ) AS pt
```